# Custom button looks different on lower API in Android

Tags: android, xml, button, android-studio, android-custom-view

hello i tried solution posted on Stack overflow but not working please help on this problem.Am using custom Button which is in drawable folder

button_selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_pressed" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

button_pressed.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#009688"/>
        <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/header" android:centerColor="@color/header" 
android:endColor="@color/header" android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

button_not_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="0.4dp" android:color="@color/header"/>
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

but on lower API screen look like this

[image]

Above API 17 it look's like this
This is the actual design i done for Button

[image]

Comment: add color white to your drawable background

Answer (score 3):

Add this in both drawable:

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: @AshwiniBhat Welcome;) if it work for you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such problem in 15 api.
Add into `shape`

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

or what color you need.
It helped me.

Comment: you not getting my question on lower API button looks different.done custom text color.But not posted that